# Cannot access iis website from internal network

Tags: iis, server, ip, internals

I'm facing with the following IIS issue:
From DC01 and external networks, i can access the website with the external domain like: https://app.domain.com/application
But from AS01 and workstations on the LAN, i cannot access the website with the external domainname

Setup:
DC01 (192.168.1.2) < domaincontroller with DNS (a record is added: app.domain.com to external IP)
AS01 (192.168.1.4) < ISS and website running on this machine

The whole firewall is temporary disabled

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance

Disabled firewall
Add DNS a record